# crossfading div backgrounds on :hover - possible in CSS?

Tags: css, background

Is there a way to smooth the transition during a div background change? Ideally I'd like to do this within the css, and not use any js.

In my css I have:

```
.examplediv {
   background: url(img_img.png);
}

.examplediv:hover{
   background: url(brighter_img.png);
}
```

It's doing what I'd like it to do (changing pictures), but if there was a way to make the two backgrounds "dissolve" into one another, I'd start frothing at the mouth with gratitude.

Note: The effect I'm going for is essentially an opacity change, so if it's easier to code a dissolve with :opacity, I'm all ears!

Tanks!~

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible using just CSS. See this Fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ffqdmcws/

HTML:

```
<div class="crossfade">
  <div class="static"></div>
  <div class="hover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.crossfade {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.static, .hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.static {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/200/food');
  opacity: 1;
}

.hover {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/200/cats');
  opacity: 0;
}

.crossfade:hover > .static {
  opacity: 0;
}

.crossfade:hover > .hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In this case I've got a container div using the `crossfade` class, and a couple of other divs inside that, using classes `static` and `hover`.

The `static` class contains the background to be shown initially, and the `hover` class contains the background to fade to on hover. The initial opacities are 1 for the `static` class and 0 for the `hover` class, so you only see the div with class `static`.

Then, if you hook up the hover action on the container div using `.crossfade:hover`, in order to set `opacity: 0;` for `static` and `opacity: 1;` for `hover`, that hides `static` and shows `hover`, when you hover over the container div.

Finally, to make the backgrounds overlap use `absolute` positioning of the two internal divs, so they're on top of each other at all times. Additionally, for the true crossfade effect you need the `transition: opacity 1s ease;` rule, which says you want the opacity to transition over a period of 1 second instead of switching instantly. Both the divs changing opacity from 1->0 and from 0->1 give you the crossfade effect of the background images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pseudo elements which are absolutely positioned. One is visible by default and another one on hover.

```css
.examplediv {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.examplediv:before, .examplediv:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.examplediv:before {
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/07/19/17/38/flower-851725_960_720.jpg)
}

.examplediv:after {
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/12/07/23/56/pink-flower-1081646_960_720.jpg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.examplediv:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.examplediv:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="examplediv">

</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ndv62h8z/)